# What is the advantage of the wilderness farm?

Tags: stardew-valley

The 1.1 update brought 4 alternative farm map layouts, each focusing on a different skill: whereas the standard farm focuses on farming, the forest farm focuses on foraging, the hill-top farm on mining, the riverside farm on fishing, and the wilderness farm on combat.

These alternate maps also provide other advantages compared to the standard farm in exchange for farming space, such as being able to fish on the farm what you'd normally have to go to town for, or unique weeds and ores. However, I can't seem to find a unique advantage for the wilderness map, which not only has less space for farming, but also has monsters spawn during the night.

Is there any advantage to the wilderness farm, or is it meant to be some kind of "hard mode"?

Comment: I think that's just it.  I don't play this game, but it appears that that's all the wilderness farm has to offer from reading around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The monsters are the advantage. Just like you don't need to leave your farm to fish for the riverside farm, you don't need to leave your farm to fight for the wilderness farm. You get loot + exp the same way you get fish + exp.

Comment: I fail to see how that is an advantage, considering you'll be going to the mines anyway.

Comment: Sure, but you'll be going to the areas with water anyway, even when you're playing on the riverside map, and same for the other areas and the "normal" locations to obtain things. It's convenient to have access to river/minerals/forest/monsters nearby.

Comment: The action _is_ the juice.

Answer (score 1):

It has a unique monster that drops fiber and seeds...though the wiki claims it levels up with your combat level, so maybe it has better drops the better a hunter you are?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is kind of an old question, but I'm currently playing on the wilderness map and since my combat level went up to 10 monsters from the skull cavern have started spawning along with the others, so you can get some neat loot without spending the day in the desert.

Comment: Which monsters, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Despite of leveling up your *combat skill* progress and catching fish, you can also fight an unique monster that only appear on that map, which is the "Wilderness Golems", like the monster on the Lvl 30-40, but they are dark green and can loot wild seed when killing it.

If you want to get more *combat skill* and also play like a challenge on Stardew, I recommend this type of farm because, you can't do many things when the night approach, on 7 p.m. more or less, since the monsters that spawn on the farm (usually bats and wilderness golem at the beginning) can kill you easily if you went to the mines and lose some health points. Also this type of farm take away a part of your farm, and you gonna get as some space as you can.

**EDIT**: There is a cool thing that can toggle off the mobs of the map. Tip: you need to go to the new area to do it. With this, you can have a challenging map withouth the challenge and less water than the River map.

Comment: Double check your answers before posting them, I have no idea what you're trying to say in your second paragraph.

Comment: I edit them and I think know it is more clear. Just play on that farm is a challenge. If you are a newbie on this game, dont pick this. It is hard at the start of the game since you can do nothing on the night without a nice sword and some health points.

Comment: So you're just repeating what other answers said.